# JSON - How to extract data recieved from django response?

Tags: javascript, django, json

My response looks something like this :

[{"0": "k@k.com"}, {"1": "p@p.com"}, {"2": "n@n.com"}, {"3": "b@b.com}, {"4": "k1@k1.com"}, {"5": "z@z.com"}, {"6": "k2@k2.com"}]

I am trying to read this through the following html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){


        document.write('Getting JSON response...');
        $.getJSON(<my django url>,
            function(data) {
            alert("receiveng"+data["0"]);
            });
    });

</script>

</head>


<body>
</body>
</html>
```

But I am not getting any alert box with the data , just the Getting JSON response..... line  is printed on screen.

Here is my return statement :

```
return HttpResponse( simplejson.dumps(result) , content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: Never use `document.write` in any type of callback : it shouldn't be executed past the initial code execution. Fill a paragraph and append it to your page instead (or use console.log during debug).

Comment: Could you show us your view? Just based on looking at the small snipped of jQuery it should work.

Comment: The response is printed on screen as :

[{"0": "k@k.com"}, {"1": "p@p.com"}, {"2": "n@n.com"}]

and when i run the html , it just gives a blank page with getting JSON response..... printed on it.

Comment: please add the code to your `django view`

Comment: What you get for : `alert(data);`?

Comment: I don't get any alert box when i type alert(data) , i tried that too.

Comment: try to add `.fail(function() {alert( "error" ); })` at the end of `$.getJSON` function. Anything happens?

Comment: @viktorovich : no , i am not getting any response whatsoever in this case too!

Comment: @viktorovich : when i tried running the file on a local xampp server ,  it didn't turn out the expected result , but atleast the function was executed and the alert message (err0r) showed up.

Comment: Instead of having an array of objects, just create an array. That probably does not solve your problem, but will make it easier to work with the data later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help guys.

the data [0][0] notation worked.

while running the loop until the data[i][j] value turned out to be undefined ,
I used :

data[i][i.toString()];
and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your JSON format, that can not be parsed/evaluated. For example, any JSON object is looks like this :

```
[
    {"attributeName1":"value1", "attributeName2":"value2"},
    {"attributeName1":"value3", "attributeName2":"value4"}
]
```

but in your JSON example you have `attributeName1` as `0`. It is the same thing if we give a name to variable as `0`. Like `define 0 = k@k.com`. It is impossible. Try to change it to something like `id0`.

Comment: The JSON is valid and there is no problem to convert it to a JavaScript array of objects. It is just a bit unusual. Once it is parsed, you can access `""k@k.com"` with `data[0][0]`. You are right in so far that variable names cannot be numbers, but property names can.

Comment: Yes, you are right. when I did `$.parseJSON` it parsed it to objects. but it is impossible to do `data["0"].0`. So it gives an error or when it is returned with response or when it is received in `getJSON` handler.

Comment: Yes, but that's why you use bracket notation. `data[0][0]` is valid and works. That's the same reason why we use `arr[0]` to access an element of an array and not `arr.0`. Whenever property names are numeric, you have to use bracket notation to access the value.